# What pedal cage is compatible with size 14 shoe?

Tags: shoes, size, toe-straps-clips

Are there toe clips/straps that are oversized to comfortably fit a men's 14/15 shoe?

Comment: Shoes (even at the same foot size) come in a variety of physical dimensions. Do you mean cycling shoes, regular running shoes, sneakers, hiking boots, etc?

Comment: Also remember that metal toe clips can be modified with two pairs of pliers.  Plastic ones not so much,

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of strapless clips on Wiggle which come in extra-large. An example is this https://www.wiggle.co.uk/mks-steel-toe-clips/

> Top Features: 3 sizes Medium Euro 36-40 Large Euro 40-44 X-Large Euro
>   44-48

44-48 Euro is size 12-15 US, 11-14.5 UK